# TypeScript, Tailwind and React. Making a nav responsively change into a hamburger menu

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I have a little nav section that I want to have change into a hamburger menu when you view it on a mobile device. I am a bit stuck as to how to do that.

This is my code:

```
      <div className="flex m-12">
        <img className="store-page-logo" src={Logo} alt="logo" />
        <div className="flex items-center">
          <div className="text-xl font-extralight">
            <a className="ml-24" href="#about">
              About
            </a>
            <a className="ml-24" href="#pricing">
              Pricing
            </a>
            <a
              className="store-login-btn text-xl font-extralight absolute right-0 mr-12"
              href="/login"
            >
              Login
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I am working with React, TypeScript and Tailwind CSS. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 `div`s (nav and hamburger menu) and hide the hamburger at desktop screen sizes (hiding the nav for mobile screen sizes).

Here is a Tailwind Play sandbox. You can change references from `class` to `className` to use the code in React.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/gyYJXV99oV

Comment: You you be able to give me an example of how to get the burger icon?? and the code perhaps??

Comment: Mostly i get icon from ```https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.query=hamburger``` as a Svg file format here a little example to use Svg in react ```https://codesandbox.io/s/react-live-editor-forked-4wq5zp?file=/src/index.js``` @JenniferDeGoede